# Set header from URL Rewrite on Azure Websites - AppCmd or applicationhost.config?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, url-rewrite-module

I'd like to set a request header (HTTP_HOST to be precise) from Web.config, using the IIS URL Rewrite module, on Azure Websites. Basically I'd like to have something like this in my site's Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="My rule" enabled="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_HOST" value="my value" />
      </serverVariables>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
```

This results in an error that HTTP_HOST is not allowed to be set. This is normal and with standard IIS the next step would be to add HTTP_HOST to the `<allowedServerVariables>` element to applicationhost.config directly or through AppCmd. However I couldn't find any hints on being able to access this config somehow.

Is it possible to somehow modify the apphost config, or add allowed server variables somehow else?

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to alter Azure's ApplicationHost.config by applying xdt transformations.

Upload the file to the /site and restart your site for the changes to to take effect:

**ApplicationHost.xdt**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <allowedServerVariables>
          <add name="HTTP_HOST" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
        </allowedServerVariables>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

See also:

1. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples
2. http://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/web-sites-transform-extend/

Comment: Thank you. I think this came with Site Extensions.

Comment: Might want to be careful using `xdt:Transform="Insert"` because it may corrupt your web app instance altogether as it will try to add a duplicate entry in your `applicationgHost.config` everytime it is evaluated. Probably safer to use `xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"` instead

Comment: You also need to specify `xdt:Locator="Match(name)"` otherwise XDT only matches the `<add>` element name, which isn't useful at all!

Answer (score 1):

[Expanding on Joris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26433105/159145), you should use `xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"` and `xdt:Locator="Match(name)"` otherwise it won't work the way you expect it to ([here's an example of it not working as-expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048138/azure-web-apps-fails-to-reverse-proxy-to-wordpress-site/63213228#63213228), [and another example](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1893)).

So your `applicationHost.xdt` should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <allowedServerVariables>
          <add name="HTTP_HOST" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
        </allowedServerVariables>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This xdt:Locator="Match(name)" worked for me...Thanks!