# Where should <allowedServerVariables> tag live in Azure Website applicationHost.config?

Tags: azure, iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

***Technical Information***

- `Azure Website`
- Installed [`IIS Manager Site Extension by shibayan`](https://www.siteextensions.net/packages/IISManager/)

***Scenario***

I have implemented a reverse proxy on my `Azure Website`, however the receiving server doesn't get any indication of whether the initial request was over `HTTPS` or not.

What I want to do is send the `HTTPS` flag of `ON/OFF` from the initial request to the proxied server, via  a custom `HTTP Header`.

***In Theory***

- Using [`shibayan`](https://www.siteextensions.net/profiles/shibayan)'s [`IIS Manager Site Extension`](https://www.siteextensions.net/packages/IISManager/), I can edit the `applicationHost.xdt` file, give it a Transform to insert an `<allowedServerVariables>` tag and that should allow me to set a custom `HTTP Header`.

***In Practise***

I've configured my rewrite rule as such:

```
<rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
  ...
  <serverVariables>
    <set name="HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS" value="{HTTPS}" />
  </serverVariables>
  ...
</rule>
```

And have attempted a few combinations of where to put the `<serverVariables>` tag...

*Attempt one:*

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26433105/912545).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <proxy enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
    <rewrite>
      <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
      </allowedServerVariables>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Result:

> HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
>
> The server variable "HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS" is not allowed to be set. Add
>   the server variable name to the allowed server variable list.

*Attempt two:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="~1[app service name]" overrideMode="Allow">
    <system.webServer>
      <proxy enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
      <rewrite>
        <allowedServerVariables>
          <add name="HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
        </allowedServerVariables>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Result: HTTP 500.50

*Attempt three:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="" overrideMode="Allow">
    <system.webServer>
      <proxy enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
      <rewrite>
        <allowedServerVariables>
          <add name="HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
        </allowedServerVariables>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Result: HTTP 503

*Attempt four:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="[app service name]" overrideMode="Allow">
    <system.webServer>
      <proxy enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
      <rewrite>
        <allowedServerVariables>
          <add name="HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
        </allowedServerVariables>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Result: HTTP 503

I am aware that in the `applicationHost.config` file for an `Azure Website` there are a few places that `<system.webServer>` can be defined, such as under the following elements:

- `<configuration>`
- `<configuration><location>`

...however I've tried these combinations to no avail.

***Questions***

- Is there another possible location?
- Have I misconfigured my `.xdt` file in any way?
- Am I missing something from my `applicationHost.config`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create a `applicationHost.xdt` file under the site folder `d:\home\site\applicationHost.xdt` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
  <system.webServer> 
    <rewrite>
      <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
      </allowedServerVariables>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now you can use the new variable in your web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>           
            <rules>
                <rule name="Proxy">
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS" value="{HTTPS}"/>
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**See also** https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-transform-extend/ or https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples

Comment: You must specify both `xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"` **and** `xdt:Locator="Match(name)"` when working with `<add>`-type collections in XML config files, otherwise XDT will only copy-over the first element if the target is empty, instead of merging all elements as-expected. I've edited your answer for the sake of people who will copy-and-paste your code without looking at it.