# Azure web apps fails to reverse proxy to Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, azure, reverse-proxy

Can anyone tell me how to setup a reasonably standard reverse proxy arrangement on an Azure website?

I wish to have the (Azure hosted) www.site.co/blog display the (non-Azure hosted) wordpress site at blog.site.co so that users don't see an Url change.

ApplicationHost.xdt is uploaded.

```
 <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">  
    <system.webServer>
        <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <allowedServerVariables>
                <add name="HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
                <add name="HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
                <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
            </allowedServerVariables>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Web.Config includes:

```
<rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^blog/?(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="https://blog.site.co/{R:1}" />
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL" value="https://blog.site.co/{R:1}" />
        <set name="HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS" value="{HTTPS}"/>
      </serverVariables>
    </rule>
```

I'm getting the following error:

"HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The server variable "HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL" is not allowed to be set. Add the server variable name to the allowed server variable list."

Comment: Did you restart the webapp after updating the xdt file?

Comment: Yes. No change.

Comment: Removing the "?" from the match improves the result for /blog/ and the redirect works.

/blog fails though and nothing is masked

Comment: Where did you upload `ApplicationHost.xdt` to? It needs to be at `d:\home\site\applicationHost.xdt` and **not** in your `d:\home\site\wwwroot` directory.

Comment: I tried both locations.  No change on localhost or an azure testing slot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"` to set multiple child-elements of the same parent with the same tag-name (`<add>`) you need to also use `xdt:Locator="Match(name)"`, otherwise the XDT system will only insert the **first** `<add>` element.

So in your case, the XDT system is only inserting `<add name="HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS" />` but won't copy the other elements because there's already an `<add />` element present.

(I feel that XDT *should* be improved throw an error if a source transform document specifies multiple `Insert` or `InsertIfMissing` elements without a `xdt:Locator`)

So change your `applicationHost.xdt` to this:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">  
    <system.webServer>
        <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <allowedServerVariables>
                <add name="HTTP_X_USE_HTTPS"                xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST"            xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                <add name="HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL"            xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"            xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
            </allowedServerVariables>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```